# Kali linux ,Ошибка импорта конфигураций

Tags: kali-linux

Error opening 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/360zip$Temp/360$0\WinDev2108Eval-disk001.vmdk' for reading (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).Не удалось импортировать конфигурацию C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/360zip$Temp/360$0/WinDev2108Eval.ovf.

Error opening 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/360zip$Temp/360$0\WinDev2108Eval-disk001.vmdk' for reading (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Код ошибки: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
Компонент: ApplianceWrap
Интерфейс: IAppliance {86a98347-7619-41aa-aece-b21ac5c1a7e6}